# Tableviewcells not selectable in tableview edit mode

Tags: ios, uitableview, edit-tableview

I have a tableview cells with 4 different type of cells. I need to edit only two types of cells. So i have added a long press gesture recognizer to the two cells. Now i need to delete these two kinds of cells. So in the long press gesture recogniser function, i have added a UIMenuController with a delete button as UIMenuItem. Now in the Delete function I am setting the tableview in editable mode.

```
- (void)Delete:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"\n Delete Selected \n");

    [mTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

-(void)addLongPressGestureRecognizerForCell:(UITableViewCell *)tableViewCell{

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lLongPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressGestureFunction:)];
    lLongPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.3;
    lLongPressGesture.delegate = self;
    [tableViewCell addGestureRecognizer:lLongPressGesture];
//  [lLongPressGesture setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    mTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lLongPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressGestureFunction:)];

    UITableViewCell *lTableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [lTableViewCell removeGestureRecognizer:lLongPressGesture];
}
```

Now when the table is in editable mode, I am not able to select the two type of tableview cells. Also the delegate method **willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath** is **not** **called**.

The buttons on the left of the tableView in editable mode are not getting tapped. I only need the buttons on the left to be tapped in edit mode and not the entire cells.

Should I remove the gesture recogniser for the cells in the editable mode?

Should I enable the selection of the cells?

I have tried all the options but no Luck. I am running out of options for this implementation but Alas!!!. Can someone please explain about any change that has to be implemented for the cells to be selectable in edit mode of a tableView?

Below is the code for Long Press Gesture Functionality

```
- (void)longPressGestureFunction:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UITableViewCell *lTableViewCell = (UITableViewCell *)recognizer.view;
    [lTableViewCell becomeFirstResponder];
    UITextView *lMessageTextView = [lTableViewCell viewWithTag:103];

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        UIMenuItem *MenuDelete = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete" action:@selector(Delete:)];
        UIMenuItem *MenuForward = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Forward" action:@selector(Forward:)];
        UIMenuItem *MenuAddToContacts = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add To Contacts" action:@selector(addToContacts:)];

        mSharedMenu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
        [mSharedMenu setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:MenuDelete, MenuForward, MenuAddToContacts, nil]];

        /*Change the position of the target rect based on Sending messages or Receiving messages*/
        if ([lTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"SendingChatCellIdentifier"]) {

            [mSharedMenu setTargetRect:lMessageTextView.frame inView:lMessageTextView.superview];

        }else if ([lTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"ReceivingChatCellIdentifier"]){

            UILabel *senderNameLabel = [lTableViewCell viewWithTag:100];

            [mSharedMenu setTargetRect:senderNameLabel.frame inView:senderNameLabel.superview];
        }

        [mSharedMenu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding long press gesture is requirement or your need? Cause you can detect the tap in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and check for your cell types otherwise add uiview in Uitableview cell and add long press gesture in that uiview .

Comment: Its not a requirement. Its a need. I need to give 2 to 3 options like Delete, Forward and Copy for the cells. So i thought i can have a long press gesture with UIMenuItems as these options.

Comment: Try to add UIView in table cell as subview and add gesture in that view.

Comment: How will it help my cause? I want my cells to be selected in the edit mode. How will adding the UIView in TableViewCell as subview help here?